# Create multiple Checkbox on Userform based on the no of records available in sql query

Tags: sql-server, vba

I want to create a userform in vba where there will be multiple check box based on the data available in the database.

Comment: So what does your code look like at the moment?

Comment: cmdlal.CommandText = "   Select distinct name FROM Table "
        
        
        Set rslal = cmdlal.Execute
      rslal.MoveFirst
i = 0
With UserForm1.CheckBox1
    ''.Clear
    Do
        .AddItem
        .List(i, 0) = rslal![Forecastobjectgroup3]
        i = i + 1
        rslal.MoveNext
    Loop Until rslal.EOF
End With

rslal.Close
cnlal.Close

Comment: [edit] your question to include the code and any other additional information.

Comment: How about creating all check boxes in advance and hide those that you don't need?